# How can I programmatically query if a domain/website is being penalized by Google?

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-search-console

There are plenty of websites that can check if a site is penalized, including Google's webmaster tools.  I need a scripted method to do this as I have to monitor hundreds of domains.  Is there a Google REST interface, API, or sample code for this?